# What do the tour groups want?

Tags: ios, oh-edo-towns

In Oh! Edo Towns, tour groups come and stay at your inns. How do you unlock more tour groups, and what does each group need in order to accomplish their task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do you unlock more tour groups?**

The best answer I could find is from [this blog](http://koukoupuffs.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/210/#trav) and seems to have been copy-pasted all over the web. However, the author admits that these may not be completely accurate.

- Elementary School Trip – available from start
- Heartbreak Club – available from start
- Ogre Vanquishing Tour – available from start
- Nation-Wide Tour – unlocked when the Komon Combo is created?
- Govt. Inspection Tour – unlocked when total Yield is greater than 50,000? (Maybe between 50,000 – 60,000?)
- Ako Clan Samurai – 30,000 Yield and unlock the Samurai House.
- Friendship Alliance – unlocked after Edomae Combo is created?
- Prince’s Secret Tour – ???
- Pumpkin Products PR – unlocked from Traveler combo?
- Gas Survey Tour – unlocked after obtaining the option to research the Elekiter Shop?
- New Home Search Team – Have a total of 3 Zoos (anywhere on the map).
- Kairobot’s Journey – unlocked after placing all 46 unique combos on the map and reaching 50 years.

**What do they need to accomplish their task?**

My experience has been that their percentage complete rises over time as the group visits shops and spends money.

I found one guide that claimed "Having crafts and combos through building placements will attract more visitors," but it's not clear how they arrived at that conclusion, so I'd take it with a grain of salt.